# Passphrase vs. Brute Force Attacks

Tags: security

Why are passphrases more secure than normal passwords? (p%9y#k&yFm?)

Wouldn't it be easier to crack a passphrase than a normal password, since it only contains letters?

And is there any way to make passphrases more secure?

Comment: Thomas M gives a good answer, but there's nothing about a passphrase that requires it only contain letters. Typically when security folks say passphrase, they mean a long, meaningful phrase, *including spaces*. But it could still have punctuation, digits, mixed case or whatever else. (As a counter-example, the famous XKCD comic https://xkcd.com/936/ is an excellent scheme, but isn't what security people have traditionally meant by a "passphrase.")

Answer (score 1):

In a brute force attack against a passphrase, since there are generally more characters, it takes longer to crack if just guessing.

Ex:

Password - e7%2b

**Number of possible solutions: 128 ^ 5 = 34,359,738,368**

(5 is number of characters, 128 is character amount in ascii for example)

Passphrase - iloveicecream

**Number of possible solutions: (2 * 26)<sup>13</sup> = 20,325,604,337,285,010,030,592**

(13 characters, 26 * 2 (lowercase and capital) amount of letters)

A detailed attack can try and guess words based on other words, ex. with ice it could guess cream, but it still takes a long time to process.

Obviously, a super long passphrase is ideal but `iloveicream` is a very simple password for a person to remember which is why it is often said to be the best.